# Adding UIView's as subviews and determining their position in the view hierarchy in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I am using a Swift library called SAConfettiView: https://github.com/sudeepag/SAConfettiView

I want to add a 'confettiView' at the top of my view hierarchy so it is not obstructed by anything else but I still want the UIButton's, UITableViewCell's etc to be selectable, how can I do this in code?

**Below is the code I am currently using:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // Create confetti view
    confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)

    // Set colors (default colors are red, green and blue)
    confettiView.colors = [UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.40, blue:0.27, alpha:1.0),
                           UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.78, blue:0.36, alpha:1.0),
                           UIColor(red:0.48, green:0.78, blue:0.64, alpha:1.0),
                           UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.76, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0),
                           UIColor(red:0.58, green:0.39, blue:0.55, alpha:1.0)]

    // Set intensity (from 0 - 1, default intensity is 0.5)
    confettiView.intensity = 1

    // Set type
    confettiView.type = .Diamond

    // For custom image
    // confettiView.type = .Image(UIImage(named: "diamond")!)

    // Add subview
    view.addSubview(confettiView)
    confettiView.startConfetti()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not checking out third party code, but if it's properly written, you can - at the very least - use "UIView.bringSubview(ToFront:UIView)".

Of course, if the confetti truly **is** at the top of your hierarchy, it is - meaning, it's **not** obstructed.

Comment: Just to confirm when I say top of the view hierarchy I mean the top most item on the screen (I may be wrong in saying 'top').

Comment: If it's topmost on the screen, then it probably interferes with touches, right? It appears to be a UIView that would be the top-most Z layer. Probably the best you can do is add your UIButtons in such a ay that they are not obstructed - either in a spot where this confetti UIView isn't obstructing the, or as a subview within the confetti UIView. I think I can say that I know what you want... but can you say that you have seen a working example?

Comment: It does interfere with touches and I have not seen example with the 'confetti' in front of all the other views only behind.